# Getting Coordinates for X and Y of two consecutive touches

Tags: android, touch, touch-event

How can i get X and Y position of touches of double tap events, maybe like a game where you select the initial position and final position so i get `oldX,oldY` and `newX,newY`

I have tried an `if...else` statement with a `boolean` `firsttouch` initially to `true` and modifying this boolean in both `if` and `else` since i only want to get two touches.

Note: I am not talking about dragging;

Comment: the question title does not match the content, and what have you tried ?

Comment: in onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) you can get event.getX() and event.getY().

Comment: ya i tried that but it enters both `if` and `else` while going to `onTouch`

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the Double Tap event using `GestureDetector` as below:

> ```
> GestureDetector gd = new GestureDetector(this);
>   gd.setOnDoubleTapListener(new OnDoubleTapListener()
>     {
>         public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e)
>         {
>             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Single Tap Called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>             return false;
>         }
>         public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e)
>         {
>             return false;
>         }
>         public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e)
>         {
>             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Double Tap Called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>         }
>     });
> ```

Comment: How can i make a `class` extending `SurfaceView` have it?

Comment: Sorry , I am not getting your question.

Comment: i have a class which extends SurfaceView and has a canvas ondraw method i want to get the initial and final position for the player.  and player wants to move a specific person in his game team from a position to another.